# Fetch with authorization and cors?

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

Is there a way to call the [clash royale API](https://developer.clashroyale.com/) from a browser, with a different origin?

The API requires a authorization header.

I'm trying to use `fetch()`, but whether or not I use mode cors, it doesn't work.

Comment: maybe you need a token or maybe they don't want other people to touch their API. But I bet on token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the API, the documentation says,

> Keys help in controlling access and traffic to the API. When creating a key you need to specify the IP addresses that are allowed to access the API endpoints.

So basically you create an API token and specify the IP addresses that make the call to the API. In such a case, the API will allow those listed IP addresses to make calls.

[image]